# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java

Tags: java, apache-storm

When attempting to run a storm job using maven, I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project avalFP: An exception occured while executing the Java class. aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project avalFP: An exception occured while executing the Java class. aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :avalFP
```

Any insight into what the issue might be would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Note: this was the result from running

```
mvn -X compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology
```

Comment: the exception message says you don't have `aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology` in your class path. Do you have it somewhere?

Comment: Do you have aval.fp.TwitterFeedTopology in your src/main/java ; if not add it there.

Comment: yes it is there.  and, in fact, it does see it, as it enters its main and executes code from it for about 10 minutes before displaying said error.